# Is there a way to open .msg files in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, office-interop

I am trying to simply retrieve a outlook email file name along with its local path, and open that .msg file via outlook. Is there a method to achieve such? or is it entirely impossible?

I DO NOT need to read the contents of the .msg file. I just need to open it so the end user can view the saved email file.

I did the following but it does not work at all.

```
try { 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); 

string filePath = MapPath("~\\path\\filename.msg"); var item = app.Session.OpenSharedItem(filePath) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
    string body = item.HTMLBody; int att = item.Attachments.Count; 

} catch (Exception ex) { 
Global.Log.Error(ex.Message, ex.InnerException); 
}
```

Comment: "does not work at all" is not helpful. Are you getting an error? If so, what? I suggest you get rid of the try...catch so that we'll see the helpful traceback.

Comment: As you are using `asp.net` tag - I assume we are talking about web-application. If this your controller/page code - you should know, that you are opening Outlook via interop at **server**-side, not at client-side.To open it on client-side, you should allow your user to download it with correct MIME-type.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel it does not produce an error. IThe code runs and nothing happens. The exception object is also null

Comment: @vasily.sib How do I do that? Can you point me to some appropriate documentation?

Comment: @ZWaltrz `IThe code runs and nothing happens.` I bet something *does* happen - Outlook on the server opens up, on the application pool account's desktop. I suspect you've tested this code only on a development PC until now, and if you check, you'll find some ghost Outlook instances running.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one possible way - automate Outlook from a JS code which is run inside IE or use the `mailto` protocol:

```
var link = "mailto:target@example.com"; 
 // In addition to this you can add subject or body as parameter . 
 // For e.g. 
 // "mailto:target@example.com?subject=test subject&body=my text"
 window.location.href = link;
```

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article states the following:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.
>
> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

In such cases, you may consider using EWS if you deal with Exchange profiles/accounts only. Also, you may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or just any third-party wrapper around that API.